# What Is Wrong With My Move Queue Why Do Inputs Get Repeated?

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to make a simple snake esque game using love2d and I cant seem to figure out what the issue with my code is. The error when running it is that the character moves are based on a queue system and it seems to be getting backed up by the same input. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
love.window.setMode(704,704)



function love.load(arg)
  x = 0
  y = 0

  timer = 0
  points = 0

  moveQueue = {}

  playersize = 32
  screensize = 704

  Applex = love.math.random(0, screensize / playersize) * playersize
  Appley = love.math.random(0, screensize / playersize) * playersize
end





function love.update(dt)

  --Inputs
  if love.keyboard.isDown( "s" ) and moveQueue[2] ~= 's' then
    table.insert(moveQueue, 's')
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown( "w" ) and moveQueue[2] ~= 'w' then
    table.insert(moveQueue, 'w')
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown( "a" ) and moveQueue[2] ~= 'a' then
    table.insert(moveQueue, 'a')
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown( "d" ) and moveQueue[2] ~= 'd' then
    table.insert(moveQueue, 'd')
  end


  timer = timer + dt
    local timerLimit = 0.15
    if timer >= timerLimit then
        timer = timer - timerLimit

          if moveQueue[1] == 'w' and y > 0 then
            y = y - playersize
            table.remove(moveQueue, 1)
          end
          if moveQueue[1] == 's' and y < screensize - playersize then
            y = y + playersize
            table.remove(moveQueue, 1)
          end
          if moveQueue[1] == 'a' and x > 0 then
            x = x - playersize
            table.remove(moveQueue, 1)
          end
          if moveQueue[1] == 'd' and x < screensize - playersize then
            x = x + playersize
            table.remove(moveQueue, 1)
          end


        if x == Applex and y == Appley then
          points = points + 1

          Applex = love.math.random(0, screensize / playersize) * playersize
          Appley = love.math.random(0, screensize / playersize) * playersize

        end



        print('Tick')
    end



end



function love.draw()

  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", x, y, playersize, playersize)

  love.graphics.setColor(255,0,0)

  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", Applex, Appley, playersize, playersize)

  love.graphics.setColor(255,255,255)


end
```

Sorry for the long read!

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to know because I'm not sure what the functionality of your game is supposed to be. If it's supposed to be exactly like snake then there are some things that you are doing which I am really confused by, like the queues.

I made a few adjustments though that see like they improve the functionality of it a little bit. I used elseif's instead of ifs(only one key can be pressed down at a time this way) and I moved the `table.remove(moveQueue, 1)` out of the if statement(this way something is removed from the queue every time `love.update(dt)` is called, regardless of whether a key is down or not.

I don't know if this does what you want though, because I'm not sure how your game is supposed to function.

```
love.window.setMode(704,704)

function love.load(arg)
  x = 0
  y = 0
  timer = 0
  points = 0
  moveQueue = {}
  playersize = 32
  screensize = 704

  Applex = love.math.random(0, screensize / playersize) * playersize
  Appley = love.math.random(0, screensize / playersize) * playersize

end


function love.update(dt)

  --Inputs
    if love.keyboard.isDown( "s" ) and moveQueue[2] ~= 's' then
        table.insert(moveQueue, 's')
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown( "w" ) and moveQueue[2] ~= 'w' then
        table.insert(moveQueue, 'w')
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown( "a" ) and moveQueue[2] ~= 'a' then
        table.insert(moveQueue, 'a')
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown( "d" ) and moveQueue[2] ~= 'd' then
        table.insert(moveQueue, 'd')
    end


    timer = timer + dt
    local timerLimit = 0.15
    
    if timer >= timerLimit then
        timer = timer - timerLimit

          if moveQueue[1] == 'w' and y > 0 then
            y = y - playersize
          elseif moveQueue[1] == 's' and y < screensize - playersize then
            y = y + playersize
          elseif moveQueue[1] == 'a' and x > 0 then
            x = x - playersize
          elseif moveQueue[1] == 'd' and x < screensize - playersize then
            x = x + playersize
          end
          table.remove(moveQueue, 1)


        if x == Applex and y == Appley then
          points = points + 1

          Applex = love.math.random(0, screensize / playersize) * playersize
          Appley = love.math.random(0, screensize / playersize) * playersize

        end

        print('Tick')

    end

end


function love.draw()

  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", x, y, playersize, playersize)
  love.graphics.setColor(255,0,0)
  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", Applex, Appley, playersize, playersize)
  love.graphics.setColor(255,255,255)

end
```

Comment: Ahhh sorry for not being clear enough I just wanted a queue system for the game I was going to add other functionality later